# How do I connect to the mysql server from the html page upon button click?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to connect to *MYSQL* database.

My code:

```
 E-mail: <input type="email" id="email" size=25><br>

<button id="go" onclick="register()">Go</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function register(){
        var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "yourusername",
        password: "yourpassword"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected!");
    });
}
</script>
```

When I open console it shows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I have **nodejs** installed and have also installed *MYSQL* from cmd using the command:

```
npm install mysql
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`require` doesn't exist on the client (at least not natively). The code you have is meant to be run on the server (node.js).

Try putting this into a file, say `main.js`, and then run `node main.js`.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "yourusername",
    password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Comment: but it should be connected only when I press the `Go` button

Comment: you need to learn about the difference of JS on node.js and JS in the browser. They are *completely* separate machines!